# Зачем вы здесь?

Tags: обсуждение

Хотелось бы узнать причины посещения сайта от постоянных посетителей. Что заставляет вас ежедневно заходить на ru.stackoverflow (хэшкод на момент публикации вопроса)? Отвечать на вопросы? Комментировать? Что вы получаете от этого сайта?

Comment: - Интересные вопросы поддерживают умственную активность в должной форме
 - "Уважение" добавляет некоторого азарта

Comment: Чё нада, чё приперлись))) ИМХО @ikoolik 200% ответил за всех!

Comment: Я программист! Я живу этим!

Comment: Хочу набрать карму **+100500** :D

Comment: а почему не +100^500?=)

Comment: Аккуратнее, такие разговоры могут вывести @cy6erGn0m'a из спячки ))

Comment: если учесть какими стахановскими темпами набирает репутацию [Котик\_хочет\_кушать](http://hashcode.ru/users/4149/котик_хочет_кушать/reputation/), скоро в топе будет именно он=)

Comment: Да я не медленнее набираю, просто людей отблагодарил.

Comment: а кого-то за живое задело, кажись =)

Comment: А почему вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Я зарегался здесь неделю назад, и заметил, что по интересующим меня меткам, отвечают в основном те же самые люди, причем скорость ответа поражает. И судя по комментам, можно говорить об образовании некоторого социума. Мне стало интересно, что движет этими людьми )

Comment: На самом деле активность проявляют не всегда одни и те же люди. Если вы посмотрите история [зала славы за неделю][1], то увидите, что то одни пользователи проявляют больше активности, то другие. Само сообщество достаточно большое.


  [1]: http://sezn.ru/standings/?index=0&period=week

Comment: упс, я на первом месте ) тем не менее мне кажется что этот рейтинг считается неверно потому как он показывает разницу в очках уважения за неделю. к примеру @exec сделал много верных ответов, но потратил более 500 очков уважения и оказался в конце списка. по мне так правильней показывать заработанные очки за неделю.

Comment: Поискать ответы на то о чём не знаю я, и ответить тем кто спрашивает о чём я знаю.

Comment: Поискать ответы, поотвечать на вопросы пользователей)

Comment: А ещё можно в резюме оставить ссылку на свой профиль на Хэшкоде :)

Comment: > Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является
> верным, форум - не подходящее место для статистических
> исследований и реальной ценности подобные темы не имеют.

> Не стоит задавать вопросы, предполагающие спорные и субъективные
> ответы.

Comment: @karmadro4, не будьте таким нудным

Comment: Тем не менее, community wiki на вопрос явно стоило бы поставить.

Comment: @Spectre, тонны неформатных вопросов нуднее :-)

Comment: Люблю помогать людям и слушать профессиональных людей :)

Comment: Начал изучать веб месяца  4-5 назад, а месяц назад начал делать свой сайт, так сказать, практикум по всему тому, чему научился. Начали появляться вопросы, откопал такой сайт, как этот, и понеслась)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Для меня Хэшкод - это ресурс, на котором я могу:

1. Получить решение конкретной проблемы. Если не полное, то хотя бы вектор, куда копать.
2. Узнать, какие еще технологии и техники я не затрагивал в своем самообучении.
3. Помочь кому-нибудь советом и внести свой небольшой вклад в развитие русского IT. =)

А самое главное - что все это без лишнего флуда и растекания мыслью по древу. Просто и лаконично.

Comment: Присоединяюсь.

Comment: было бы хорошо обсуждать целые куски или скрипты, так, как к примеру я незнаю у кого к примеру спросить , что у меня не хватает в скрипте или что нужно добавить!

Answer (score 68):

1. <s>Прокрастинация.</s> Форма отдыха и свободного времяпровождения.
2. <s>Вахтёрство.</s> Систематизация и организация знаний.
3. <s>Фаллометрия.</s> Возможность наглядно продемонстрировать квалификацию.
4. <s>Кармафермерство</s>. Получение знаний в новых областях.
5. <s>Сублимация общения</s>. Общение с единомышленниками.
6. <s>Самоутверждение за счёт остальных</s>. Альтруистическая помощь окружающим.

[image: Прокрастинация]

Comment: Ты еще немного здесь? У тебя домен snowlands.ru увели, теперь там какая-то богомерзкая реклама казино...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Забил болт на сайт. Наверное, надо вычистить его из внешних ссылок. Или оставить как напоминание о прошлом...

Answer (score 55):

Уж не знаю, могу ли я назвать себя постоянным посетителем, но отвечу. Кратенько.

**Знания**. Я обогатил свой арсенал приемов проектирования(в первую очередь высокоуровневого) в разы с тех пор как начал регулярно посещать хэшкод. Заслуга тут, разумеется не только(да и не столько) сайта, но наиболее изощренные приемы отсюда =)

**Навыки**. Если почаще решать чужие задачки, особенно те, что не дублируют основную деятельность - не слабо развивает мозг =)

**Общение**. Такое какое здесь присутствует без ')))))))!!!!!111' (JS не в счет), без нытья (по большей части), и с людьми, которые хорошо и понятно отвечают на правильные вопросы  =)

P.S.: И пусть кто не согласен, тот первый бросит в меня минус =)

Comment: Кстати, да, кол-во неадкеватов на ресурсе стремится к нулю (лишь бы не накаркать, тьфу-тьфу-тьфу)

Comment: ...ибо злые после вио на мэйле и гугле адекваты таких сразу поливают кислотой)

Comment: А я вот всегда боялся вио на мэйле. Пару раз всего сталкивался, Но мне казалось, что там вменяемых людей вообще нет =)

Comment: Я сунулся как-то по наивности... Там, например, можно узнать, что "линукс это то-же самое ,что и винд и mac" и увидеть такие шедевры, как Самоцветы Плоти ("Flesh gems") или Идет Тощий ("Movi macer", lat.). В общем-то я, кажется, объективно и всесторонне описал сей ресурс)

Comment: Для поддержания качества вопросов и ответов каждый участник, набравший достаточное количество баллов или написавший администрации о своем желании модерировать, может редактировать и удалять сообщения, тем самым обороняя сообщество от т.н. неадыкватов. Каждый может внести посильный вклад в это благое дело :)

Comment: к чему и стремимся )

Comment: А что c JS не так?((

Comment: @bitrixhater как я понял, это кусок кода на нём.

Answer (score 50):

Уже кучу раз прихожу сюда (или на StackOverflow), открываю «задать вопрос», начинаю формулировать. Ясен пень, смотреть на двухэкранную портянку кода никто не будет — делаю прототип, иллюстрирующий суть дела, минимизирую, свожу к ядру проблемы.

Дальше — ну, хотя бы, надо же показать что я тут не «сделайте мне» пришел — начинаю из высказанного описывать варианты, как я пробовал решать задачу и почему это мне не подходит.

Оказывается, что все, в реальности, не так страшно как казалось — какой-нибудь вариант да, на самом деле, подходит. Получаю общее направление решения. Оставляю вкладку болтаться на фоне, ухожу смотреть чем направление закончится, делать прототип. Работает, зараза!

Закрываю форму — вопроса больше нет. Спасибо дорогому сообществу!

Comment: Тонко подмечено.

Comment: Да, иногда даже жалко выкидывать контент :)

Был бы я блоггером, моя газета проблем-решений пополнилась бы уже статьями 20 — теми, на которые я нашел ответ сам в процессе изложения проблемы на Хешкоде.

Answer (score 27):

Знания. Здесь бывают нетривиальные задачи( не только по программированию ). При чем, эти задачи никто не сочиняет сам, т.е они возникают не сами по себе, а на чьей-то практике, т.е в реальной жизни. Поэтому, решив такую задачу, ты во-первых повышаешь свой опыт, а во-вторых избавляешь себя в будующем от таких же проблем, которые возникли у других.

Comment: Вот кстати одно из уточнений меня тоже зацепило если не в первую очередь, то во вторую точно. Именно что "реальные задачи", а не абстрактное "собака гавкнула 15 раз за час, а кошка - 21, найдите чатоту гавов".

Comment: из 10 задач такая бывает одна, в основном всё сводится к "как сделать красную рамочку вокруг воооон того дива" и "односвзяный список: скандалы, интриги, расследования"

Answer (score 23):

Наверное просто не хватает *профессионального* общения.

А еще частенько задаю вопросы, когда хочу **быстро** получить информацию.

Answer (score 21):

Сообщества такого рода повышают уровень знаний по интересующим направлениям. 
Ты не ограничен рамками своего опыта и Гугла, а можешь объективно посмотреть на возникшую проблему, попробовать предоставить максимально оптимизированное решение проблемы на всеобщее обозрение и посмотреть как эту же проблему решили другие люди.  Очень немаловажно, что при этом ты помогаешь другим людям. 
Так же, очень важным является ЧСВ (Чувство Собственной Важности) в таких сообществах.

Теперь немного пофантазируем :)
Такие сообщества растут очень быстро и я уже вижу время, когда при оценке уровня специалиста будут указывать количество баллов в таких сообществах.

Comment: Вот насчет баллов не надо. Думаю это далеко не главное.

Answer (score 19):

1. скучно, убиваю время
2. если получилось кому-то помочь - круто:)
3. регулярное посещение ресурса позволяет анализировать вопросы которые задают новички
4. интересно сравнивать разные позиции людей/ответы касательного определенного вопроса/проблемы

Answer (score 18):

Мне сайт понравился сразу, перечислю почему:

1. Сайт сделан правильно, продумана классная система репутаций и т.п.
2. Он русскоязычный, понятный язык
3. Правильно заданный вопрос почти всегда имеет шанс на быстрый ответ
4. Сообщество нормальных кодеров сдесь большое)
5. Посмотрите на список меток, и вы поймете как много различных технологий вы можете изучать и получать достойные ответы
6. Порешать задачи, где я хорошо разбираюсь, очень даже полезно и интересно
7. Расширить кругозор и понимание системы вцелом при помощи чтения вопросов и ответов
8. Провести время не в (бесполезных) социальных сетях, а за любимым занятием
9. Понять свой уровень знаний, сравнив себя с участниками
10. Прочитать опыт и истории о том, как у кого что в жизни получилось, а где были обломы в сфере IT

Этот ответ я составил за 5 минут включая печать. Чем не заслуга Хэш Кода =)

Comment: Ну конечно, есть целая куча сайтов, но этот ориентирован на практические нужды больше других, с помощью такой организации сайта все намного лучше воспринимается. Может только я мало сайтов посещал, но это вряд ли

Comment: спустя год хотел бы заметить, что к сожалению не очень много вопросов именно по моей технологии. Это может быть только из-за узкопрофильности и не большого количества пользователей этого сайта. Но с общем здесь не плохо задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 18):

1. Сею доброе/вечное.
2. Плюс (правда редко) узнаю что-то новое для себя - в основном о тенденциях рынка, новых технологиях
3. Держу себя в форме.

Answer (score 16):

Сам определенное время назад начинал с нуля. Искал решения простых по сути вещей на просторах сети. А, теперь, так сказать "отдаю долги" :). Вести целый блог по вопросам разработки - лень. А здесь, когда есть свободное время, можно ответить на интересный вопрос.

Также, тут собралось сообщество сильных программистов, и можно поучаствовать в интересных дискуссиях, в которых открывается что-то новое.

Answer (score 13):

я не программист или разработчик, более того — мне скоро 36 — не изучал информатику даже в школе. В арсенале лишь несколько прочитанных книг для новичков по смежным с программированием областям. Стать профессионалом силёнок не хватит, да и никогда не хотел этого: не знаю, поймут ли здесь или нет, я рассматриваю программирование прежде всего как *средство*, а не *цель*, — а посвящать жизнь средству не желаю.

Зарегистрировался, когда при вёрстке своего сайта долго мучился, почему не подошёл [отмеченный галочкой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/96749/199934), и решил [уведомить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494978/199934) других пользователей, чтобы они не попадались, как я. Те самые кавычки, за которые пришлось [отбиваться](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2663/199934) от опытных пользователей Меты и получать несколько минусов.

Уже не один год пребываю в депрессии, иногда становится прямо совсем плохо. И вот подметил, что чтение материалов по IT-тематике помогает на короткий период забывать о Ней, а время по субъективным ощущениям заметно ускоряется. Так и остался здесь справляться со своими трудностями. Не знаю, надолго ли, — возможность моего бана тоже никогда не исключал.

На дух не переношу оскорблений, хамства, обсценной лексики, [явно неконструктивных методов ведения дискуссии](http://web.archive.org/web/20160317231932/http://xpomo.com/ruskolan/tolpa/piramida.htm). Не идеализируя Stack Overflow, отмечу, что его атмосфера не в пример лучше по сравнению с большинством сайтов Рунета, — пусть же так будет и впредь, — ещё одна причина, почему задержался.

Также обожаю получать знания, — когда-то в очном противостоянии с Анатолием Вассерманом отстал от него всего на 4 ответа, — и делиться ими. Раз, не умея программировать, набрал 1000 баллов репутации, значит, наверное, тоже могу приносить здесь какую-то пользу. Вижу у проектов формата Stack Exchange большое будущее, и надеюсь, что оно не испортится неумелым управлением.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если работа совпадает с хобби, то это хорошо же.

Answer (score 12):

Мы находимся здесь, чтобы внести свой вклад в этот мир. А иначе зачем мы здесь? (Стивен Пол Джобс). Мы здесь, чтобы поделиться своими знаниями и почерпнуть новое для себя, найти ответ на вопрос и т.д.

Answer (score 9):

*"Если ты не можешь объяснить что-то шестилетнему ребенку, то ты сам этого не знаешь"* - есть мнение, что так думал А.Эйнштейн. Я не раз в этом убеждался, пытаясь те или иные вещи, связанные с web dev, объяснить кому-то, кто не в теме.
Потому помощь новичкам - своего рода укрепление казалось бы тривиальных знаний.
Кроме того, только постоянной практикой можно поддерживать навыки на должном уровне, а где, как не тут, эту практику по рандомным задачам получить?
Ну и, конечно же, приятно получить плюсик в карму за помощь нуждающемуся, ведь мне самому подобной помощи на первых парах очень не хватало...

Answer (score 9):

Откровенно говоря, в основном просто отдыхаю :) Иногда попадаются интересные вопросы, и тогда к отдыху добавляется развлечение :)

Это когда отвечаю.

Ну, а когда спрашиваю - то, само собой, чтобы получить нужную и проверенную информацию.

Answer (score 8):

Мне тут не раз помогли, особенно в начале, когда я вообще ничего кроме фотошопа не знал.

Вот если знаю, чего, может тоже помогу кому-то.
А потом, мне кто то поможет.

Осведомленность вообще о проблемах которые встречаются в практике, о нюансах.
И собственное развитие.

Клёво же!     :-)

Answer (score 8):

- Расширение, приобретение дополнительного опыта.
- Самообучение.
- Решение ступорных задач (ведь нерешаемых задач не бывает).
- И ещё... ХэшКод, а теперь StackOwerflow — **это аналог какого-то коллективного разума. Хоть и не гиперактивный, но всё же коллективный**.

И всё это вытекает в саморазвитие и повышении уровня квалификации как специалиста перед работодателем или же для своего ИТ-бизнеса или даже хобби.

Т. е. StackOwerflow вкупе даёт возможность развития человека в целом.

Answer (score 6):

Часто прихожу сюда для интересных головоломок, предлагаемых авторами, ради чего-то такого что я не знал или не понимал. А когда задаю свой вопрос - то это формулировка вопроса так, чтобы просматривающие могли понять с налёту, без уточнений. В этом случае помогает правило - правильно заданный вопрос уже половина ответа, и в большинстве случаев это опять же играет на руку и в итоге я сам отвечаю на свой вопрос, часто раньше всех, так как они остаются даже без комментариев ;)

Answer (score 4):

Бабла поднять.
Как "уважение" на wmz вывести?

Answer (score 4):

Для меня этот ресурс, это возможность помочь кому-то найти решение некого камня преткновения, главное чтобы человек понимал что он делает, как и почему, а направить в правильное русло дело приятное как для меня, так и для большинства участников ресурса. В свое время меня направляли на правильное решение задачи, что помогло в какой-то момент вырасти как специалисту в своем профиле. Поэтому возможно для меня - это своеобразная возможность отдать "долг" и научить или помочь кому-то в саморазвитии.

Answer (score 4):

Этот топик никогда не перестанет быть актуальным. Поэтому пишу.

1. > Лучший способ обучаться - отвечать на вопросы, а не задавать их.

   Не знаю автора цитаты, буду рад, если кто-то подскажет. Но это основная причина, почему я здесь.
2. Приятно помогать другим.
3. Здесь я ищу решения проблем. Обычно не задаю вопросы, а именно ищу. Здесь накопилось много знаний. Грех не воспользоваться.
4. Есть такие вопросы, которые тяжело нагуглить ([пример 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1502896/), [пример 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500084/)). Да, они могут показаться глупыми, но например важны для меня. Тогда задаю спрашиваю здесь.
5. Участие в код-гольфе. Да, это весело, даже если не претендуешь на победу. Интересно решать задачи, смотреть, как это решили на других языках. И узнавать про некоторые редкие языки, ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1544162/532877)).