# Давайте решим, что нам делать с вопросом о поиске работы

Tags: предложение, тематика, удаление-вопросов, диалоги-о-работе

[Как вы нашли работу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3889/181472)

Вопрос был закрыт и имел 6 голосов за удаление, в том числе мой. Потом он был переоткрыт, в результате чего все голоса за удаление были аннулированы. Поскольку повторно голосовать за удаление нельзя, всё что мне остаётся — призывать к удалению данного конкретного вопроса на Мете.

---

В ту же печь:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/56000/181472
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/241471/181472
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/268772/181472

Comment: Другое мнение -- давайте просто оставим старые отвеченные вопросы в покое.

Comment: Мое мнение наверно ощибочно, но я хотел бы, что вопросы про книги\работу и т.п. как-то пополнялись, развивались, пусть даже без прокачки вверх рейтинга авторов. ИМХО, эта информация важная и быстро устаревает. А значит требует регулярного обновления и новых ответов.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: судя по моему опыту, процесс трудоустройства меняется гораздо медленнее, чем версии какого-нибудь языка программирования. =) А вопрос пересоздали на Мете, вот он: [Как вы нашли работу?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Historic lock

Вариант действий - повесить на этот вопрос historic lock и оставить его в покое. Тогда:

- Он останется доступен для тех, кому приятно и ценно почитать ответы.
- Репутация авторов не пострадает.
- На нём будет явно написано, что он не является примером хорошего ответа.
- Нельзя будет голосовать, давать новые ответы и даже комментировать. Флуда не будет точно.

Comment: Плюс. Но вообще, а как можно найти вопросы с историческими блокировками? Насколько я помню, из обычного поиска они исключаются.

Comment: @Qwertiy: в избранное добавить можно.

Comment: А именно поиск? Или логи как для очередей проверок?

Comment: @Qwertiy: не слышал о таком. 100% можно будет найти через поисковики, т.к. им безразлична внутренняя система обозначений на сайте.

Comment: Раз через поисковики дотуп есть, то можно и лочить.

Comment: @avp: вопрос тут скорее о том, лочить или удалять.

Comment: `<sarcasm>` 
Под вопросом можно будет разместить табличку: «Вопрос знаменит тем, что ему посвятили больше всего букв в чате StackOverflow на русском». `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 6):

Для того, чтобы принять решения, давайте очень кратко рассмотрим несколько базовых вопросов. Как мне кажется, в большинстве своем, сообщество согласно с ответами на них.

**Что такое Stack Overflow на русском?**

Stack Overflow на русском это:

- Сообщество разработчиков и энтузиастов программирования.
- Свободная база прикладных решений.

**Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?**

Наша основная цель – упросить и ускорить получение новых знаний по программировани за счет создания базы знаний и размещению её в свободный доступ.

**Что делать, если я программист и хочу задать вопрос, который не соответствует тематики сайта или его формату?**

- Не задавать его.
- При крайней необходимости опубликовать вопрос, не подходящий по какому-либо критерию для сайта, в чат.

**Каким образом выразить свое мнение о вопросе на сайте?**

Любым из доступных Вам инструментов:

- голос «за» или «против»;
- голос за закрытие или повторное открытие вопроса;
- сигнал тревоги;
- назначение конкурса по вопросу.

**Как выразить свое несогласие с правилами сайта?**

Опубликовать вопрос на Мете, содержащий:

- конкретную критику с обоснованиями;
- варианты решения проблемы (улучшения правил).

**Как *не* стоит выражать свое несогласие по вопросу или правилам?**

Не стоит разводить жаркие дискуссии в самом вопросе или в чате, если речь идет о правилах сообщества.

**Чего не стоит делать категорически на Stack Overfow на русском?**

Все мы, включая меня, [даже в сложившейся ситуации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/), собрались здесь исключительно по своей инициативе. У каждого своей ответ на вопрос «[зачем вы здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/)»: кто-то из-за возможности помочь тысячам разработчиков, опубликовав лишь один развернутый ответ, кто-то из-за возможность восполнить недостаток профессионального общения, а кому-то просто нужно решение сложной задачи, но, уверен, все мы положительно и с уважением относимся к коллегам. На сайт недопустимо:

- любая грубость;
- проявления любого неуважения к другим участникам сообщества;
- любые выпады, особенно личного характера.

Да, иногда хочется высказать свое мнение, особенно тогда, когда оно кардинально отличается от мнения другого уважаемого в сообществе знатока. Самое главное не забывать про культуру общения и про то, что с следующее утро может начаться, например, не с кофе, а с чувство сожаления. Мнение субъективно, факты объективны!

### Что думает администрация сайта по поводу указанного вопроса и других аналогичных ему?

На мой взгляд, следует учесть все выше сказанное и:

- В сообществе есть огромное количество участников, которые знают правила Stack Overflow (особенно англоязычного) и функционал движка Stack Exchange на порядок лучше меня. Я каждый день узнаю у них что-то новое.
- Правила сообщества не перманентны, перманентна лишь миссия проекта – сделать Интернет лучшим местом для поиска информации по программированию. Мы сами создаем правила русскоязычного сообщества сами, и в дальнейшем корректируем их в зависимости от нужд, потребностей и размера сообщества, согласно нашей миссии.
- Один из самых важных аспектов проекта заключается в том, что вы нигде не найдете такой информации как на Stack Overflow, так как все вопросы и ответы были созданы реальными людьми и отражают уникальный опыт.

**Таким образом**

Всем содержимым сайта управляет сообщество, именно вам надо решать, что делать, коллеги! Но! У проекта есть миссия, а также существуют правила, согласно которым мы вместе объективно можем прийти к правильному решению или изменить правила для его принятия.

Со своей стороны я вижу, что указанные вопросы не соответствуют правилам сайта принятым на *данный момент*. Если бы вопросы были заданы *сегодня* я был бы полностью согласен с их закрытием и последующим удалением. Проблема лишь в том, что они были заданы в тот момент, когда подобные вопросы хоть и были «на грани фола», но не удалялись с целью поддержания интереса к проекту существующего на тот момент небольшого, но дружного коллектива.

В ответах отражен реальный жизненный опыт, причем не одного участника. На мой взгляд, к сожалению, просто удалять подобные вопросы будет неэтично. Следует либо оставить вопрос *закрытым*, либо перед удалением, представить опубликованную информацию в другом виде. Отличны пример «преобразования» информации – вопросы с литературой по программированию.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение о переоткрытии вопроса.

Comment: Раскройте идею предоставления "в другом виде", пожалуйста.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вопрос должен быть закрыт. Он не соответствует _настоящим_ правилам сайта.

Comment: @Discord К сожалению, у меня нет _быстрого_ ответа на этот вопрос. Было бы здорово вынести его на открытое обсуждение сообществом: нужны ли такие вопросы, если да, в каком формате. Если нет, то что делать с существующими. Отличное решение было найдено, например, как я писал, с базовыми вопросами вроде «что почитать» – мало того, что все новые вопросы мгновенно закрываются, так они действительно полезны людям! Возможно вместе мы придумаем как представить и эти данные в одном унифицированном формате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky почему закрыт а не залочен?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не вижу в это проблем (кстати, она бывает двух видов). Идея в том, что, да, вопрос не соответствует _текущим_ правилам, но есть участники, которые против удаления. Как результат, необходимо искать какой-то компромис.

Comment: Подчеркну. Если бы вопрос был задан сегодня, я бы сам его удалил бы, так как он физически не может быть задан в формате вопросов и ответов Stack Overflow. Любая сложность на нашем не простом пути – это потенциальная возможность улучить правила сайта!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я полностью согласен, что когда вопрос задавался, это было разрешено, и поэтому нельзя осуждать авторов ответов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а что касается компромиссов, вот вам два на выбор: залочить и перенести на Мету.

Comment: Предлагаю объявить мораторий на «охоту» за старыми популярными офтопичными вопросами до финального общего решения.

Answer (score 3):

## Удалить

Это тотальный оффтопик. И то, что он популярен, не добавляет ему ценности.

К нему можно было бы применить historic lock, но вот беда — ни вопрос, ни ответы не имеют ценности, так что historic lock тут по определению не подходит.

Давайте его просто удалим. И будем удалять впредь все вопросы в жанре форумного флуда.

---

Можно сказать, что жаль удалять ответы, потому что это отнимет репутацию у авторов и им просто будет неприятно. Давайте вспомним о миграции содержимого с Хэшкода на SO. При этом репутация была пересчитана по новым правилам и у многих участников она оказалась меньше чем была. Да, это очень досадно, но по новым правилам нового сайта произведенные действия приносят именно столько репутации.

Так вот, по правилам и в рамках тематики Stack Overflow на русском обмен мнениями и историями из жизни приносит ноль репутации. Давайте считать это частью процесса миграции.

Comment: Для желающих перечитывать истории из жизни можно добавить вопрос в избранное и иметь к нему постоянный доступ вне зависимости от удаления/закрытия и т.п.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: Только начиная с определённой репутации.

Comment: @VladD а остальные просто и не знают про этот вопрос =)

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: Я знал о вопросе про ZALGO безотносительно к репутации на en.SO.

Comment: @VladD Да, довольно известный ответ, но здесь я просто озвучил некоторые вещи, которые могли быть упущены при обсуждении этого варианта.

Answer (score 3):

## Создать подсайт `offtopic.ru.stackoverflow.com`

На нём можно будет собрать околопрограммистские интересные старые вопросы.

Отдельный сайт позволит также задавать новые подобные вопросы.

Для новых вопросов, чтобы не заваливать сайт бесполезным содержимым можно установить более строгие правила, например:

- автоматически удалять, если ни вопрос, ни ответ на него не собрал, к примеру, +16
- запрещать публикацию вопросов на подсайте, если репутация не достигла 1000
  (это граница просмотра числа голосов на enSO)

У этого варианта ещё есть дополнительны плюс, что его можно будет использовать для анализа вопросов и расширения тематики основного сайта.

> Новый под. сайт – это новый сайт вопросов и ответов, то есть вы предлагаете открыть ответвление аналогичное сайту «пользователей» или «системных администраторов»

Нет, я не предлагаю новый сайт вопросов и ответов.
Я предлагаю зависимый сайт с той же связью, как сейчас у основного и меты:

- Единая репутация, точнее, репутация основного сайта распространяется на подсайт
- Возможность перемещения вопросов между сайтами без вмешательства модератора
  (не по теме → принадлежит другому сайту)
- Требовать достижение минимального рейтинга для публикации вопросов
  (для меты это вроде 5, но я предлагаю ставить лимит в разы выше - 1000)

---

Или даже вообще не разрешать на нём публикацию, а просто выбирать при голосовании за закрытие - принадлежит другому сайту (если представляет ценность) или закрыть/удалить (если не представляет).

Comment: 1) Так или иначе в результате это будет новый сайт с новыми правилами и своей тематикой, которая не соответствует модели вопросов и ответов Stack Exchange.  2) Сейчас в Stack Exchange существует жестко заданная архитектура «один сайт – один под сайт». Изменение архитектуры всех 150 сообществ ради 10 вопросов выглядит не оправдано. Но самое главное, 3) зачем выносить то, что не соответствует правилам сообществ на другой под сайт, не проще ли просто удалить?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, выносить именно то, что имеет ценность. Правила стандартные кроме тематики - сообщество само голосованием решает, представляет вопрос ценность, или нет. Что касается архитектуры с одним подсайтом - во-первых, это чисто техническая часть, во-вторых, далеко не факт даже, что это техническая трудность. Т. е. мы не зная, сложно ли вообще это реализовать, говорим, что раз такого нигде нет, то и нам не надо? А может наоборот, этому примеру последуют другие сайты? А может архитектура это уже предусматривает, надо только немного настроить?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, чем вариант перенести на мету лучше этого?

Comment: Интересное предложение. Если пофантазировать, то можно представить несколько разных "view" (организуются специальными тэгами?) одной и той же базы вопросов-ответов-комментариев в которых действуют несколько разные правила (в т.ч. отображения на странице, например, новый комментарий вытаскивает тему вверх или можно представить некую смесь вопросов-ответов и чата с ссылками на блоки ответа... (подошло бы для предлагаемой тематики code review)). При этом  один и тот же материал может быть виден в разных view. Конечно, это фантазия ни чем (пока?) не подкрепленная.

Comment: Как вариант этого ответа, можно создать отдельный сайт, на котором сделать копию важных старых ответов (в том числе и уже удалённых), но уже в виде статических страниц =)

Answer (score 1):

## Оставить в покое

Предлагаю не трогать старые вопросы с достаточно большим рейтингом.
Тем более те, которые интересно почитать.

---

> [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56000/Как-стать-программистом-c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/56000/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-c)

А тут вообще ответы про книги.
Ну так и сделать его дубликатом [Книги и другая литература по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1).

Comment: Совершенно согласен.

Comment: Только применять это правило только именно для старых вопросов

Comment: @tutankhamun: только для старых вопросов, на которых уже висит historic lock. )

Comment: согласен. Все вопросы по работе тоже нужны&важны

Answer (score 0):

## Перенести на Мету.

Этот вопрос чем-то похож на "Зачем вы здесь". Он об участниках сообщества, значит ему может найтись место на Мете.

- Остается возможность читать ответы.
  Если оставить открытым - то и давать новые ответы и комментировать.
- Вопрос индексируется поисковиками.
- Вопрос полностью исключается с основного сайта и не смущает юных падаванов

Comment: Проблема в том, что в текущем виде вопрос не для Меты. Его все равно надо как-то модифицировать. «Зачем вы здесь», все-таки, о Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а возможно ли выделить отдельный подсайт, например, `old.ru.stackoverflow.com` или `offtopic.ru.stackoverflow.com`, где собирать хорошие нетематические вопросы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Таких вопросов наберется с десяток. Мне кажется, ситуация требует не отдельного сайта, а создания процессов принятия решения в сообществе и, возможно, поиску формата представления подобных данных.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, просто в случае подсайта, можно было бы разрешить новые такие вопросы. Но, естественно, с более внимательным отношением к ним. Возможно, выставить какой-то значительный порог для него, например, 1000 баллов (это порог просмотра числа голосов на enSO).

Comment: @Qwertiy Выглядит мало реалистично. Новый под. сайт – это новый сайт вопросов и ответов, то есть вы предлагаете открыть ответвление аналогичное сайту «пользователей» или «системных администраторов». В дополнение, Stack Exchange – это вопросы и ответы. На данный момент, расширенные дискуссии выходят за рамки проекта.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, написал отдельным ответом. Я не это предлагаю. Новый _сайт_ не нужен. Именно _зависимый_, как мета.