# Порядок оспаривания отклонённых правок

Tags: поддержка, отклонённые-правки, предлагаемые-правки

Здравствуйте. [Отклонённая правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/64631). я не согласен с отклонением, тем более с такой формулировкой: «Изменения абсолютно излишни или явно ухудшают читаемость.» Как оспариваются решения? В [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) не нашёл ответа.

По существу. Разъяснения к предлагаемой правке содержатся [в моих ответе и комментариях на тот же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494978/199934). Новички в вёрстке могут не знать, что использовать пробелы в именах файлов не рекомендуется, и неизбежно столкнуться с трудностями. я сам вписал путь к бэкграунду без кавычек, как в ответе ув-мого FLK, а потом долго мучился, отыскивая ошибку.

Comment: Да так и оспариваются - в чате или на Мете.

Comment: и правильно отклонили, у вас почти вся правка - добавление постороннего текста. Если хотите чтобы было с кавычками - напишите комментарий автору

Comment: @BOPOH, 1) «Посторонний текст» был написан, чтобы обойти ограничение в 6 символов на правку, добавление кавычек содержит только 2. В нём самом, собственно, и содержалась просьба удалить себя. // 2) Автор ответа неактивен с 2012 года: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6551/flk?tab=answers . Спасибо.

Comment: В конкретном данном случае мне кажется стоило добавить комментарий к ответу, например такого содержания: *Для путей в которых содержится пробел, необходимо весь путь заключать в кавычки*, я думаю Вам стоит воздержаться от правок, по крайней мере пока. Почитайте мету, посмотрите правки других пользователей с большим рейтингом, иначе подобные ситуации будут повторяться

Comment: Ув-мый @Bald, 1) я дал комментарий с тем же смыслом, только ссылкой на свой ответ,  // 2) Новички, не проставившие кавычки, будут мучиться, пока я воздерживаюсь от правок? Для людей они прежде всего. Спасибо.

Comment: Кажется у нас есть робовьер http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/65209 =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, кто из них?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, Nofate, т.к. правка меняет суть ответа

Comment: _"Автор ответа неактивен с 2012 года"_ - нет, последний ответ _7 май '14 в 20:47_ - переключи сортировку с голосов на новые. А на вкладке профиля есть запись _Последнее посещение 10 май '15 в 8:32_

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не, правка просто бесполезна, но ничего не меняет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, меняется название тэга. Это можно отнести к правке сути вопроса. Можно же было и `div` (утрирую) туда вкрячить.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вот `div` было бы даже лучше. А у вопроса метка [tag:регулярные-выражения], а не [tag:html] ;)

Comment: > Последнее посещение 10 май '15 в 8:32 — Да, прошу прощения, невнимательность проявил. Но всё равно год отсутствия:  неизвестно, ответит ли пользователь.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вы посмотрите вопрос целиком. После того как был дан ответ, ТС исправил опечатку в вопросе и ему пришлось исправить опечатку в ответе, чтобы избежать неконсистентности.

Answer (score 7):

Не стоит вносить правки, меняющие суть ответа, если он не отмечен как "общий". В большинстве случаев, это не приводит ни к чему хорошему. Вы просто считаете себя умнее автора ответа, и "коверкаете" его слова, внося правку. Да, автор ответа может быть не прав, но вместо правки, лучше указать ему на неправоту в явном виде. Для этого есть следующие способы:

1. Написать комментарий, содержащий развернутое мнение о том, почему ответ *ошибочен/вреден*.
2. Поставить *плохому* ответу "минус". А если вы еще и пунктом 1 воспользуетесь, то есть шанс что автор ответа его исправит.
3. Написать свой ответ, лишенный [фатального недостатка](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA) *плохого* ответа.

А еще эти способы можно комбинировать ;-)

Comment: 1/2 — не всегда хватает репутации + как я писал выше на этой странице, автор ответа давным-давно неактивен. я абсолютно и ни коим образом не «считаю себя умнее» ув-мого FLK, а правку предложил исключительно потому, что его пример корректен не для всех случаев.

Впредь, — если сейчас не доминусуют до снижения привилегий, — не буду вносить правки, меняющие суть ответа, выражая мнение в комментариях. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы всегда можете создать еще один ответ, в явном виде подчеркнув в теле ответа, что другой ответ ошибочен. Для этого не нужны дополнительные привилегии. И еще: минусы на мете не влияют на карму на сайте ;-)

Comment: О минусах. 1) Почему правка выгоднее нового ответа. Пользователи, перешедшие на stackoverflow в поисках решения своей проблемы, прежде всего смотрят на самые рейтинговые ответы. Мой там заминусован, тогда как у ответа, где в разметке не использованы кавычки, 2 плюса. Очевидно, что советом с отрицательным рейтингом вряд ли много кто воспользуется.// 2) Ответ ув-мого FLK вовсе не «ошибочен», но в нём не предусмотрена одна деталь. В своём ответе я как раз это и подчеркнул: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494978/199934 // 3) меня минусите, но кавычки добавьте. Спасибо.

Comment: * [фатального недостатка](//lurkmore.to/Фатальный_недостаток)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, спасибо

Comment: @СашаЧерных, а вообще, лучше поменьше трогать старые ответы (и вопросы). Посмотрите, тут новых и вообще неотвеченных тыщи штук уже.

Comment: Ув-мый @avp, лучший подход: «Не знаешь — не лезь», «Уверен — отвечай» вне зависимости от возраста вопроса. В примере с кавычками я был уверен в своей правоте, на личном опыте убедившись в необходимости их проставления. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, нет. Совсем не так. Старые вопросы стоит поднимать **только** если у Вы можете сказать что-то **действительно интересное** для общества** (поскольку для ТС все это уже почти всегда неактуально).

Comment: В вашем ответе есть фатальный недостаток! )

Answer (score 5):

1. [Правка](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/64631) вносит чисто стилистическое исправление, причём, по [некоторым источникам](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary) оно является ухудшением, а не улучшением. Хотя в соответствии со стандартом оно допустимо.
2. Правка содержит посторонний текст, который надо удалить. Т. е. просто принять нельзя, надо жать принять и редактировать, таким образом подписав правку своим именем. Никто не хочет подписывать своим именем сомнительные правки.
3. На твоём [ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494978/178988) стоит минус (не мой), из-за того, что описанная в нём проблема никак не связана с кавычками. Если сможешь привести пример, где такая ситуация происходит именно из-за кавычек, получишь плюсик (как минимум от меня). А так - не верю.
4. Я бы и [вторую твою правку](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/65209) отклонил. Исправленный вариант настолько же некорректен, как оригинальный. Правильный вариант выглядит так:

   ```
   <details>
     <summary>Вопрос ...</summary>
     Ответ ...
   </details>
   ```

   но он совершенно не вписывается в тот ответ. Т. е. правка ничего не улучшила, но и ничего не ухудшила. Возможно, кто-нибудь её ещё откатит.
5. Как вообще комментарий

   > Прошу прощения, перепутал тэг. Спасибо.

   применим к правке чужого сообщения?

Comment: Поддерживаю, сделал откат к предыдущей версии сообщения.

Comment: Просьба обращаться на «вы», мы с Вами до сегодняшнего дня не были знакомы.//3 — связана. [Там же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/96746/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD/96749#96749), в комментарии 4 ветки я приводил пример ув-мому soledar10, могу повторить: [Отображение с кавычками](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//kristinita.ru/with_quotes.html&w=1024&h=768&a=1)/

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я посмотрел все ссылки и не увидел разницы.

Comment: [Отображение без кавычек](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//kristinita.ru/without_quotes.html&w=1024&h=768&a=1)/[Разметка с кавычками](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/with_quotes.html)/[Разметка без кавычек](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/without_quotes.html). Жду плюса.//1 — не «стилистическое», см. п.3.//2 — см. комментарии к ответу выше Dmitriy Simushev .

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я смотрел. Они выглядят совершенно одинаково. Вот: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DLxMB.jpg - ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: //4 — Тег `<details>` в отличие от `<summary>` без `<details>` не «некорректен», см. [тут](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/WwbKBj) (не работает в Internet Explorer и Firefox). При использовании `<summary>` вместе с `<details>` а) видимо, придётся задавать имя каждому спойлеру, что неприемлемо, когда нам нужно сделать тысячи спойлеров, б) усложнится (если вообще возможно) регулярное выражение, а спрашивалось хотя бы про простейший случай.//5 — Заметив оплошность в изначальном тексте вопроса, я заменил `<summary>` на `<details>` прежде всего у себя.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, https://validator.w3.org - валидатор не считает, что `summary` можно не писать. Где-то указывалось, что спецификация его требует, но сейчас найти не могу.

Comment: Ув-мый andreymal ответил до того, как я обнаружил у себя ошибку. С `summary` ничего не скроется, потому необходима правка его ответа. После отката VenZell а) спойлеры из ответа andreymal не будут функционировать, б) в вопросе `<details>` — в ответе `<summary>`, выходит несоответствие. (а вообще решение мне нужно найти, чтобы в IE и Лисе спойлеры также отображались: отбиваясь тут в комментариях, до сих пор не взялся). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, в ответе ещё скриншот. Получается, несоответствие кода скриншоту лучше? И вообще, кого в темя про регулярные выражения волнует html-разметка?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36417/discussion-between---and-qwertiy).

Comment: @VenZell, тогда нужно откатить и соответствующую правку вопроса или не откатывать вовсе.

Comment: @Nofate, упустил этот момент. Сделано. Тем более, это не влияет на суть вопроса.

Comment: @Nofate, а вопрос-то зачем трогать? Пусть исправленный остаётся.

Comment: @Qwertiy и будет несоответствовать ответу? о0

Comment: @Nofate, вопрос не обязан ничему соответствовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос - нет, ответ - должен.

Comment: @Nofate, а теперь ответ не соответствует собственному скриншоту.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я починил )

Comment: @Nofate, :D​​​​