# Вернуться на ru.stackoverflow или нет?

Tags: обсуждение

Год назад ушел со [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) - в [профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley) значится, что в последний раз заходил на сайт 25 декабря 2015 года. Причины обсуждать здесь не будем, кому не лень могут пролистать историю и все увидеть, а те кто сидит здесь больше года - и так это знают.

Перечислять свои грехи, заслуги также смысла большого нет, опять же кому надо тот знает, кому не надо - тому и дальше не надо.

Резоны за и против также бессмысленно перечислять: кто-то голосует ногами,  как например [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/), кто-то остается, кто-то уходит на другие сайты, а кто-то как я просто год молчит.

Я честно не знаю. Просто посмотрю за ходом обсуждения up/down voting'а. Это даст мне пищу для размышлений.

Да, с Наступающим!

Comment: Добро пожаловать, возвращайтесь, подвинете баланс в сторону Java, а то шарписты одолевают. :)

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить цель обсуждения. Вы только про себя говорите или вообще об участии на сайте кого-либо? Если не только про себя, тогда не следует отговаривать людей от указания явных доводов (на техническом сайте не только субъективные мнения, но и факты должны иметь значение). В сторону: статья на перевод которой на хабрахабр вы сослались является однобокой и содержит фактические ошибки (утверждения типа: *"шансы получить полезный ответ на SO близки к нулю"*—очевидный бред). Она может передавать "чувства" некоторой части пользователей, но очевидно выводы с осторожностью  стоит делать.

Comment: @jfs - я говорю только о себе любимом. Я вообще отвечаю только за себя (не считая своей семьи конечно).

Comment: @Barmaley Так что вы решили? Возвращаетесь или нет?

Comment: Да, [я вернулся](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607747/android-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: Поздравляю! Эпичнее было бы сказать "I am back.", но это мелочи.

Comment: С возвращением!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Собственно мой первый ответ касался скорее причин **не_участвовать** в SO:
Вы же уходили, значит эти причины в один момент стали для вас сильны.

Рассмотрим причины **участвовать** в SO.
Собственно есть старый-старый пост: [Зачем Вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C)

Там [ваш ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315/14963) тоже есть.

> 1. Сею доброе/вечное.
> 2. Плюс (правда редко) узнаю что-то новое для себя - в основном о тенденциях рынка, новых технологиях
> 3. Держу себя в форме.

Вероятно ваша мотивация поменялась.
Но тем не менее можно почитать тот пост и посмотреть что же здесь ищут другие люди и насколько это для Вас - актуально.

Answer (score 19):

Чтобы, понять стоит ли Вам возвращаться, надо понять почему Вы ушли, и играют ли роль эти факторы сейчас.

Я лично всей истории не знаю, потому что особо не следил за войнами на мете и вообще тогда был в инактиве:
В переходный период хешкода в ru.so мне показалось что на сайте стало очень много бессмысленного вахтерства и я с полгода сюда вообще не заходил.

Если причина была в чем-то похожем, то мне кажется атмосфера изменилась: устоялись неформальные правила игры.

Больше нет кровавых дрязг на мете между либералами и консерваторами характерных для переходного периода, нет двух радикально противоположных коалиций раздирающих один и тот же вопрос.

Никто больше не правит до неузнаваемости чересчур образные сообщения, если они никого не оскорбляют.

Бессмысленные правочные войны если и возникают, то только потому что всякие утки фармят новогодние шапки =)

Да, устоявшаяся правоприменительная практика значительно жестче того что когда-то было на хк, но по крайней мере теперь она есть. И лично мне кажется довольно адекватной.

Если причина в этом - возможно стоит вернуться и посмотреть, что из себя представляет сообщество ru.so сейчас, и насколько Вам это интересно.

Если причина - в конфликтах с какими-то участниками сообщества, то стоит уже решать конкретно с ними.

Возвращайтесь кароч)

Comment: Правила устоялись. Закрывашки победили. :( :)

Comment: @PashaPash, ну я прям так бы не сказал. Мне кажется с редакторским пылом было множество перегибов при переходе, и многие участники пытались решать большинство проблем больше по букве, чем по духу. Сейчас кмк не так. Эта разумеется только мое личное ощущение, другие участники могут ощущать по другому)

Comment: Я как то прожил год без ru.SO и наверное могу жить без него и вечно, ровно так же и без меня стэк проживет - это самоочевидно. А причина почему ушел - она уже не играет никакой, ровно никакой роли. За год что-то выкристаллизировалось, что-то очистилось, что-то наоборот потускнело, помутнело. Просто пытаюсь найти причину для возвращения - я правда, не кривляюсь, не выдумываю.

Comment: @Barmaley, ну вот мне было тут некомфортно, полгода где-то я сюда не заходил, а ща норм. Мой ответ собственно про это.

Comment: @Barmaley, раз возникала такая мысль, значит тянет сюда и рефлексировать почему так, особого смысла нет. Добро пожаловать!

Comment: @PashaPash, не победили ;) К тому же, тематика постепенно расширяется.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Ух как щасвирнус. Чую, по мне уже скучают.

Answer (score 14):

Конечно вернуться!

Если все, кому что-то не понравилось, будут разбегаться, то ruSO так и останется не тем, который мы хотели бы видеть. Надо оставаться и пытаться что-то менять!

И в случае выборов в модераторы, я проголосую за :)

Comment: Нет, я не ходок в модераторы - я понял, что это не мое

Comment: @Barmaley, жаль!

Comment: @Barmaley, ха-ха, как же всё в жизни может меняться, особенно красноречиво теперь уже красуется ромбик напротив такого утверждения))

Comment: @Sevastopol', ну передумал - и хорошо :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да я только за, и тоже кстати плюс мой голос на выборах. Просто совершенно случайно попался мне этот комментарий, и я вот обратил внимание на то, что напротив ромба он смотрится сильно!))

Answer (score 12):

Вопрос о дохлых помидорках.
Сообщество как и раньше содержит как адекватных личностей, так и кучу школоты.
Причин Вашего ухода я не знаю, а рыться в истории лень, да и её пишу победители, а не беспристрастные люди.

---

Хотите сделать мир IT чуточку лучше, чище и образованнее - добро пожаловать, иначе не стоит.
Остальное неважно в контексте вопроса.

С Наступающим!

Answer (score 3):

Рад видеть, однозначно!
Хотя бы потому, что был против ухода.
А с другой стороны - нет смысла драматизировать вопрос.
Если на Mathematics попадается интересная задачка, а на ruSO в моих темах затишье, то о патриотизме говорить бесполезно =)