# Есть ли смысл сразу давать ответ на вопрос, или лучше подтолкнуть участника, который задал вопрос, к правильному ответу?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Наверное, не всегда полезно сразу получать ответ на вопрос, а немного помочь человеку в поисках решения, и если уж совсем никак, то давать ответ на вопрос? Если такой вопрос задавался - сорри)

Comment: можно и подтолкнуть, но всегда найдется тот, кто просто плюхнет решение, пока ты там подталкиваешь кого-то)) и всё.

Comment: По разному, однозначного ответа на такой вопрос нет. Если вопрос кажется простым и видны попытки разобраться, то я предпочитаю подталкивать человека в комментариях вместо того, чтобы писать готовый ответ

Comment: К сожалению большинство задающих не хотят думать мозгом((   и подталкивание его лишь травмируют)) банально из последнего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670604/191482 ...... а стоит лишь прочитать описание функции в документации

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так может лучше написать ему типа смотри документацию и будет тебе счастья..хотя с какой стороны посмотреть, может и правда, что многие сразу за ответом приходят, ибо думать особо не хотят

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich как бы то ни было - если есть желание и время на подталкивание и видно, что человек сам интересуется, а не говорит "я ничего не понимаю - можешь написать?" - то вполне можно оттянуть момент с ответом. Главное его не забыть дать. Ведь ответ дается для всех, кто может столкнуться с подобным.. Можно еще с ним и в чат пойти, чтоб совсем оттянуть)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это решать только вам, [зачем вы находитесь на ресурсе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/213987).

Может быть, вы хотите сеять разумное, доброе, вечное... и ничто вас не сможет остановить причинить добро людям.

А возможно, эти объяснения чешут вам эго и ЧСВ.

Поэтому сначала смотрите на свои желания -- хотите, не хотите, есть время или его нет.

Потом уже смотрите на пациента и пытаетесь понять, оно ему надо или не надо, хочет ли он удочку или побыстрее схватить рыбу и убежать.

В принципе, вот и весь алгоритм -- всего в двух шагах.

Сообщество приветствует как вариант дать ответ, так и вариант научить искать ответы самостоятельно.

Answer (score 11):

### Да, стоит (если хочется и не жалко времени).

Этот способ решения вопроса принесёт ТСу максимальную пользу. Но пользу принесёт, скорее всего, ему одному.

Такая помощь это совершенно не формат StackOverflow и плохо масштабируется (в отличие от публикуемых ответов), поскольку действует, как правило, на конкретное лицо в текущий момент времени. Будущие посетители этого эффекта будут лишены.

#### И будьте осторожны:

- **Используйте комментарии.** Как правило, такие "подсказки" не тянут на полноценные ответы, и потому не должны публиковаться как ответы.
- **Не будьте навязчивы.** Будьте готовы к тому, что ТС не захочет играть с вами в эту игру. Дальнейшее навязывание такого подхода рискует привести к конфликту, *в котором ни в коем случае нельзя открывать ответный огонь*. Если ТС буянит и не хочет учиться, это его проблема. В конечном счёте, пройти мимо — беспроигрышный вариант.

  Рука может в такой ситуации потянуться к минусу у вопроса — ещё раз подумайте, скорее всего вы оцениваете автора, а не вопрос. Понятно, что обидно, но вопрос-то в этом не виноват. А если не обидно, а вопрос хорош, может, всё-таки напишете ответ?
- **Обеспечьте ответ.** В конце концов, мы же на StackOverflow. Попросите ТСа написать ответ, если он догадался. Если ТС медлит, напишите сами. Все обсуждения, которые на StackOverflow происходят, ведут или к уточнению вопросов, или к улучшению или составлению ответов. Остальное неважно.

Comment: Почему уточнения типа "он(а)" только в единственном предложении? Даёшь больше толерантности!

Comment: @alexolut fixed.

Comment: eмуй одномуй ... OMG!

Comment: @alexolut я ответил на ваш вопрос? :)

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, при создании вопроса пользователь справа видит подсказку сайта, в которой, написано, в том числе, следующее:

> Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не
>   те, которые порождают дискуссию.

По-моему, яснее не скажешь. Как о качестве вопросов, так и о качестве ответов.

Но давайте посмотрим на вопрос с практической точки зрения.

Для ОБУЧЕНИЯ есть множество всевозможных ресурсов и курсов. На которых человек именно копается, выполняет разные задания и всецело наслаждается обучением. И вспомогательные форумы таких курсов заточены как раз на то, чтобы подталкивать ученика к правильному ответу. Допустим, на одном очень популярном обучающем JAVA-ресурсе запрещено давать правильный ответ. Что полезно в образовательных целях.

Но очень часто бывает, когда разработчик сталкивается с какой-то проблемой и не может двинуться дальше. Что ж, давайте устроим ему квест, часами "наталкивая" на правильный ответ? Это будет неправильно и замедлит его работу. Да и разработчики, как правило, знакомы с синтаксисом и вопросы, которые они задают, зачастую не решить, "подумав".

Опять же, нужно прислушиваться к вопросу, очень часто вопрошающий уже своим вопросом даёт понять, хочет ли он "квест" или хочет получить точный ответ здесь и сейчас. Часто это видно по характеру вопроса.

Comment: В нашу задачу не входит ускорять чью-то работу, торопиться писать пока там у кого-то лентяя горит зачёт или у сотрудника проблемы на продакшене. Да и разработчики бывают РАЗНЫЕ. Поэтому ваша точка зрения имеет право на существование, но она достаточно узкая, чтобы охватывать множество случаев, ответы выше более широкие. Поэтому ни минус, ни плюс не поставил -- просто прочитал.

Comment: "Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не те, которые порождают дискуссию." Спасибо, однако, что Вы дали моей точке зрения право на существование.

Comment: На практике обычно такие дискуссии завязываются под вполне конкретными вопросами, ответ у которых настолько на поверхности, что жалко отбирать у ТСа радость самостоятельного решения. Для спрашивающих этот вопрос не стоит, только для отвечающих. Поэтому то, что написано в этом ответе, бесполезно, хотя технически правда.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы знаете ответ, то его нужно писать. Данный ресурс как раз и ценен тем, что ориентирован на обмен значниями, а не на обучение в виде передачи знаний с верху, от гуру, в низ к ученику. Иными словами, в принципе, здесь все равны :)

На практике, если вы видите, что ТС в чем-то заблуждается или не понимает, ну так и разъясните это в ответе явно. Он же поэтому и задал вопрос. И конечно всегда нужно помнить, что ответ дается не конкретному ТС, а нескольким с похожей проблемой.

Не стоит перегружать комментарии подсказками или, тем более, устраивать в них дистанционное обучение. Они не для этого предназначены, а для уточнения вопроса или ответа.

Comment: да, но конкретно в этом случае, человек который задал вопрос, в 90% случаев придя на данный ресурс без определенных знаний с ответом без знаний и уйдет. Лучше подтолкуть к правильному решению, если совсем ничего не получится, то уже помочь с решением задачи

Comment: Я ж написал "разъяснить явно в чем заблуждается или не понимает", поэтому он не должен уйти без знаний.

Answer (score 0):

Специализация этого интернет-ресурса - "четкий вопрос - четкий ответ". На других ресурсах и в других сферах деятельности Ваш вопрос уместный. На этом - нет.

Comment: на счет других сфер вы перегнули