# создать механизм благодарностей

Tags: предложение, комментарии

я задавал вопрос, пользователь jfs добавил комментарий, благодаря которому в итоге я ответил на собственный вопрос. однако из его совета нельзя сделать полноценный ответ, что бы он написал его и я его принял. я бы хотел дать ему "+", но в данном случае у меня такой возможности нет.

мне кажется было бы не плохо ввести нечто подобное (механизм благодарностей), это так же сократило бы благодарности в виде сообщений.

P.S. это мой первый пост на мете.

Comment: Возможность получать карму за комментарии может привести к усилению активности в комментариях в ущерб написанию ответов. Не думаю, что администрация SO этого хочет.

Comment: карма - это лишь вариант, вы уже привели аргумент не в его пользу, но можно сделать что то вроде "поблагодарили N раз", без кармы. и дать эту возможность только авторам вопроса, что бы избежать накруток

Comment: Связанный вопрос (не дубликат!): [Есть ли смысл сразу давать ответ на вопрос, или лучше подтолкнуть участника, который задал вопрос, к правильному ответу?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5270/181100)

Answer (score 9):

Комментариям тоже можно ставить плюсики (кнопка слева от комментария, появляется при наведении).

В целом же - специальный механизм "благодарностей" не требуется. Если пользователь пишет комментарий вместо ответа - значит, он не хочет ни писать ответ, ни получать за этот ответ плюсы.

Comment: я не увидел в профиле каких либо указаний о том сколько раз пользователь получал "+" в комментариях. нет отдельного показателя для этого, они существуют только в рамках вопроса.
а по поводу "он не хочет ни писать ответ, ни получать за этот ответ него плюсы." возможно, справедливо, но не учитываются мои интересы. Я сам хочу это сделать, почему я не могу поблагодарить того кто мне помог? тут не сообщество роботов, которые ответили и забыли, получить благодарность каждому будет приятно.

Comment: @Maximmka, зайдите в профиль участника, посмотрите на его ответы и оцените достойные с вашей точки зрения. Только не нужно фанатизма - много плюсов за короткий промежуток времени система откатит.

Comment: спасибо за совет, им и воспользуюсь, без фанатизма)

Comment: Комментарии на основном сайте не приветствуются. И они должны удаляться после получения ответа (с)