# Отвечать интереснее, чем задавать вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

Наблюдаю яркую закономерность. Чем больше репутация у Участника, тем меньше у него вопросов. К примеру, у первой десятки во всем ruSO вопросов от нуля до нескольких десятков на фоне нескольких тысяч ответов. Это некое негласное правило? Задавать вопросы не респектабельно? За них меньше репутацию начисляют, простой расчет? Возможно, приходит некоторое просветление, когда ответы всплывают сами собой перед глазами или вопросы просто не всплывают?

*P.S. Нисколько не принижаю репутацию уважаемых Участников. Безмерно восхищаюсь людьми знающими.*

Comment: А задавать вопросы о чем? Как сложить 2+2 на jquery? или что такое перегрузка методов, ответ на который можно найти в книге  прочитав её? на все простые вопросы (которых тут большинство) банально есть информация в справочниках и книгах (хотя печально, что нынешнее поколение не читает их, а сломя голову и бездумно несется на форумы и QA). А на сложные вопросы кто ответит?

Comment: А еще мы умеем пользоваться гуглом. Вернее предыдущий опыт позволяет правильно формулировать вопросы для него. Полтора года назад, когда я сюда пришел, из SQL я знал только диалект оракла и то 8й версии. По всем остальным диалектам я примерно знал направление куда копать, обычно минуты 2-3 поиска в гугле  было достаточно что бы сделать на незнакомом диалекте пример, убедится, что он работает и написать ответ. И если у меня у самого вдруг возникнет вопрос, я так же достаточно быстро найду в гугле то, что мне надо для решения.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а я заметил закономерность, что здесь, на ruSO, ответы на простые и очевидные вопросы сильно-сильно плюсуют. В то же время ответы, в которых есть элементы исследования, а также, те которые отвечают на вопрос _почему_ это так, а не иначе часто могут оставаться с нулевым рейтингом..

Comment: @Nikita ты так написал, как-будто в противопоставление моих слов.... ну ок......а сильно-сильно плюсуют тут java и C# . остальные в обычных среднячках

Comment: @Nikita, такое происходит во-первых потому что на простой вопрос тупо быстрее ответить (отвечаешь пока вопрос на первой страничке и будут тебе плюсики), во-вторых сильно плюсуют ХОРОШИЕ ответы на простые вопросы...ответить красиво и правильно на простой вопрос значит помочь огромному количествую людей, в-третьих простые вопросы банально популярнее и на них из поисковых систем приходит больше людей...со сложными всё наоборот...часто ответить моментально не получается, многие не могут оценить качество ответа(не хватает знаний) и не плюсуют, на них реже переходят из ПС

Comment: @Nikita Плюсуют то, что знают сами. А то что сами не понимают или слишком длинно (много букв, не осилил) не плюсуют. Хотя неплохо плюсуют еще большие научно популярные тексты, опять же, если написаны доступным языком, без кучи заумных терминов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сидишь здесь чтобы потешить эго оттого что много знаешь?

Comment: @Alex78191 да! есть проблемы с этим?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто уточнил.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский зачем написал что ничего не знаешь?

Comment: @Alex78191 особенность почти любой области: чем больше узнаёшь, тем больше (как оказывается) не знаешь. Если экстраполировать на бесконечность, получается, что знания пренебрежимо малы.

Answer (score 14):

За первый свой вопрос на большом Stack Overflow я взял [значок "Бродяга"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed). Ответ в итоге состряпал сам через несколько дней, опубликовал. Ответ мне не нравился и я надеялся на что-нибудь поэлегантнее. Но нет. Тишина.

Спустя ещё какое-то время, не дождавшись альтернатив, принял свой же ответ и забыл о произошедшем. А за год полного отсутствия активности в вопросе я его уничтожил вместе с ответом — очевидно, ни вопрос, ни ответ на него не интересовали приблизительно никого. А "статистика стала ровнее". Знаю, глупый мотив. Но в данном случае вреда это не принесло.

---

Этот случай натолкнул меня на мысль, что...

### ...лично мне просто нечего здесь спрашивать.

Возникающие у меня в работе вопросы я могу решить самостоятельно, не привлекая SO вовсе. Предпочитаю "канонические источники": официальные сайты, документацию, исходный код и комментарии к нему, эксперименты в REPL, отладчик. Заметно реже ищу публикации в сторонних источниках, которым у меня нет оснований не верить (частный случай этого: ответы на Stack Overflow).

Я могу разве что задавать вопросы, на которые уже знаю ответ и могу сразу его написать, просто чтобы "поделиться опытом". Но нужно "попасть в читателей", угадать с тем, что они будут искать. Узнав материал, зачастую быстро забываешь о том, на чём именно застрял в процессе его изучения (ведь теперь всё понял!), потому и задавать качественные в этом отношении вопросы бывает трудно.

**Да и вообще, задавать хорошие вопросы довольно сложно.** И мне, честно, попросту лень. Я избегаю труда по подготовке вопросов, отдаю на откуп тем, у кого эти вопросы изначально возникают. У них, конечно, тоже не всегда выходит. Но они обычно задают вопросы из практической необходимости, и вероятность того, что кто-то будет искать то же самое несколько выше, чем для "синтетических вопросоа". Во всяком случае, если не тренировать навыки "синтеза".

Излагал ли б я свой опыт, если б умел хорошо "синтезировать" вопросы? Тоже вряд ли, но по другой причине. По той, что свой опыт я, скорее всегд, излагал бы "от простого к сложному", оставляя связи в виде ссылок, а SO просто не предназначен для такого контента.

То есть, технических барьеров решительно нет, и есть даже полезная функциональность про это: связанные вопросы, поддержка ссылок в ответах. Дело не в технике, а в том, *чем SO является* для большинства посетителей. На SO приходят обычно из поисковика и за решением чего-то одного, конкретного. Изначально приходят не узнать *что-нибудь* новое, а нечто *конкретное*. Поглощённые текущими задачами, на связанные ответы такие посетители обычно не обращают внимания. Поэтому, по моему скромному мнению, такая деятельность будет иметь малую отдачу и не стоит требуемых усилий.

---

*При этом не нужно считать, что если я не задаю вопросов, то я ничего нового здесь не узнаю. Достаточно многое из того, о чём я пишу в ответах, я узнаю впервые. Написание ответов для меня это форма развлечения, развивающая мои навыки поиска решений в целом и приносящая пользу кому-то ещё. Такие дела.*

*И взгляните на вопрос ["Зачем вы здесь?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/181100). Там тоже есть кое-что по теме.*

Comment: Николас,перелогиньтесь, а то палитесь.

Comment: @Aid иначе что? ;)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну мульт, все дела, а он глава нашего интернет-государства.

Comment: @Aid напоминаю, что мульты сами по себе не являются чем-то противозаконным. Они влияют на назначение наказания за реальные нарушения. Пока что ваша гипотеза выглядит слабой, но продолжайте собирать улики!

Comment: @Aid у глав всегда больше прав ;-)

Comment: @D-side, как говорил мой дедушка: был бы мульт - наказание назначим.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так вроде пред законом все равны. Или кто-то ровнее?

Comment: конспирологи и сюда добрались

Comment: @МихаилРебров, как узнали? Неужели шапочка из фольги не спасла от закрытой изолентой камеры?

Comment: @Aid , у меня по соседству звезда с РЕН-ТВ живёт и к ней каждый день масоны на летающих тарелках на интервью прилетают, аж машину припарковать негде.

Comment: люблю содержательныые диалоги :-)

Comment: @МихаилРебров, Вам надо квартиру сдавать мазохистам по завышенным ценам - квартиру снимите, а маржу на печеньки :)

Comment: То есть не бывает такого, что не знаешь почему не работает?

Comment: @Alex78191 бывает. Беру и выясняю.

Comment: @D-side лучше задать вопрос потому что кто-то мог с этим сталкивать и знает как делать.

Comment: @Alex78191 есть определённый порог, начиная с которого "на проблему ушло слишком много времени". Но я как-то не успеваю его пересечь. То ли проблемы у меня унылые, то ли я Шерлок...

Comment: @Alex78191, когда на написание вопроса и ожидание ответа (или просто на написание вопроса) уходит больше времени, чем на самостоятельный поиск решения  (не в смысле поиск в интернете, а именно нахождение причины проблемы, и ее устранение), зачем вообще писать вопрос?

Answer (score 10):

Есть такое.
Это называется "опыт" и "знания" - чем их больше, тем меньше необходимость спрашивать.
Тем более что большинство здешних вопросов - частности одного и того же явления, перезаданного 1001-ый раз.
Думаю что научись каждый студент гуглить, вопросы на SO стали задавать раз в месяц. Если повезёт.
Так что проблема не в старичках и их репе, а глупости большинства; гуглим "Систематическая ошибка выжившего".

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть на корреляцию между сложностью вопроса и количеством отвеченных вопросов на всём SO, то, видится мне, картина будет весьма однозначная. Люди не хотят отвечать на сложные вопросы, с которыми не сталкивались или на которые не смогут найти ответ в гугле.

Боюсь, большая часть моих вопросов бы заняла слишком много времени на решение. Поэтому, никто бы просто не стал браться за такие вопросы. Как следствие, я почти никогда ничего и не спрашиваю.

Comment: _"Люди не хотят отвечать на сложные вопросы, с которыми не сталкивались"_ - не согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy всегда найдутся исключения. Но, согласитесь, большинство людей именно такие, как я описал.