# Интервью с топовыми пользователями

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Лично мне было бы интересно почитать истории наших топовых пользователей: зачем они здесь, чем занимаются irl и т.п.

Может стоит периодически интервью брать у наших активных пользователей? У топ-10 или топ-50 или топ-100, например?

Можно утвердить список вопросов, а потом создать вопрос, где люди будут публиковать такие интервью как ответ. Или мне одному только такое интересно?

Comment: [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/178988)

Comment: @Qwertiy да. Хотелось бы насобирать таких интересных вопросов и одним ответом чтоб люди отвечали.

Comment: См. [meta-tag:видеочат]. Чуть более живой формат. Можно его чуть изменить, добавив "блиц-опрос" об общих вещах, но интерес скорее будут представлять прицельные, персонализированные вопросы и углубление в ответы.

Comment: Ничего не получится. Т.к. ТОП с 2 по 49 - это клоны участника VladD

Comment: Мне кажется, отдельными вопросами читать интереснее. Не всегда хочется читать ответы на десяток вопросов. Да и писать их долго.

Comment: Отвлёкся на интервью — вылетел из топа.

Comment: Поддерживаю, тоже было бы интересно почитать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, сначала был **за**, а потом думаю, есть же ["Зачем вы здесь?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c), там добровольно могут отвечать. Не думаю,что все топ юзеры будут отвечать на вопросы личного характера. Впрочем, а список вопросов имеется?

Comment: @stackflow список вопросов надо ещё составить ^_^

Comment: Интервью, потом потребуют фотосессии, подиумы, автографы... И родится на SO свой шоу-бизнес :*

Comment: @Jenssen Дом 2 (SO edition)

Comment: С интересом бы послушал\почитал интервью с Barmaley, D-Side, Mike и  Мелкий. Меня их ответы натурально восхищают.

Answer (score 3):

Вот мой список вопросов:
 1. Нравится ли вам тратить время на интервью или вы [сам себе интервьюер](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c) ?
 2. Что сподвигло вас войти в IT ?
 3. Какими ЯП вы пользовались и какой ЯП вам нравится больше и почему ?
 4. Каков был ваш первый проект и гордитесь ли вы этим проектом ? Почему ?
 5. Какой проект забрал у вас "лучшие годы" вашей жизни ?
 6. Вы командный игрок или одиночка ? Почему вы так решили ?
 7. Работаете ли вы в этой сфере ? Гордитесь ли вы этим ?
 8. Хотели бы вы чтобы ваши дети занимались IT ? Почему ?
 9. Важна ли вам анонимность ?
 10. Помог ли вам аккаунт на github\stackoverflow в устройстве на работу ?
 11. Хотели бы вы работать на самого себя ? Почему да или нет ?
 12. Как вам децентрализация ? FreeNet и подобное.
 13. Реклама в интернете нужна или нет ?
 14. OpenSource головного мозга ? Или он губит работу ?
 15. Linux или Windows ? Если бы Linux был платным, то какова была бы цена ?
 16. Изучали бы вы латынь, если информация про IT в один день стала бы исключительно на этом языке ?

...
продолжение следует :)