# А вы часто пользуетесь закладкой "конкурсные вопросы"?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

В одном из ответов к [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/213987) предлагалось дать возможность участнику писать лично другим участникам.

Ответ этот ныне удалён автором, по причине большого числа минусов, однако я вполне понимаю желание привлечь внимание к вопросу. И да -- обычно это предлагается сделать при помощи механизма конкурсов.

Я вообще хочу сделать опрос, наподобие [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/213987), чтобы узнать, как часто вообще другие участники вообще открывают эту вкладку.

У меня пока нет доступа к аналитике сайта (25к+ репутации), плюс аналитика не заменит прямую речь, а только даёт косвенные намёки и подсказки.

От себя могу сказать, что я лично практически не заглядываю на эту вкладку, потому что просто держу открытыми несколько конкретных меток в браузере с новыми вопросами.

А вы?

Comment: Заглядываем. И даже конкурсы объявляем. А еще хорошо бы на Мете конкурсы разрешить.

Comment: Можно привлечь меткой [meta-tag:важно], но пока что на ней уже три вопроса.

Comment: Не заглядываю, потому что лень. Для меня конкурсы как способ привлечения внимания не работают

Comment: Думаю, на русском SO эту вкладку меньше используют(отвечающие) банально потому, что вопросов меньше и они не так легко теряются, как на "большом" SO.

Comment: @alexolut, как это - разрешить конкурсы на мете? Ведь мета не влияет на репутацию участника. Откуда будут списываться баллы? Куда начисляться?

Comment: @maestro это уже вопрос реализации. Хочется просто иметь функционал для привлечения внимания к вопросу. Можно, конечно, избраться в модераторы и ставить метку [meta-tag:важное]. Но это надо ждать импичмента кого-либо.

Comment: да, особенно для этого вопроса очень хочется добавить конкурс )

Answer (score 4):

Заглядываю в моменты мёртвого затишья в ленте новых/интересных. Раз в месяц, примерно. Из чистого любопытства, вдруг что интересное пишут, а не в попытках выхватить награду. Все свои ответы на конкурсные вопросы дал в общем порядке, просто увидев их в ленте.

Answer (score 3):

Не заглядываю по двум причинам:

1. Вокруг конкурсных вопросов (сугубо моё мнение, исходя из наблюдений, впрочем недлительных, поскольку я туда заглядывал только первое время) наблюдается иногда какой-то нездоровый ажиотаж, "толкучка" какая-то, часто всё непрерывно обновляется, приходится перегружать страницу, это сбивает с толку
2. Я редко бываю компетентен в конкурсных вопросах. У меня тоже нет доступа к статистике :P , чтобы это подтвердить (по статистике меток хотя бы), но "носом чую - литра!" :)